# Как делать auto-deploy с помощью AWS DeployCode?

Tags: github, развертывание, amazon-web-services

Прочитал документацию, может быть я что-то не правильно понял.

На стороне Amazon добавил приложение, сделал группу, деплой добавляется и вручную и автоматически с Github при каждом коммите, но всегда выдает ошибку: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS.

При этом в статусе деплоя всегда пишет:
Minimum healthy hosts: 0 of 1 instances.

Инстанс рабочий.

Где и что надо сделать, чтобы заработал Auto-Deploy?

Comment: Вебхук на гитхабе есть? Который оповещает амазон о пушах?

Comment: Нет, где почитать про эти хуки? И развер сервис не должен это же самое делать? Т.е. на какой адрес отправлять хук?

Comment: Авто деплой делается, но остается проблема с ошибкой самого AWS.

Comment: Не добавляйте решения в вопрос. Либо убирайте решённые части, либо частичные решения публикуйте ответами. Хорошо, что есть прогресс :)